# Use static google maps in desktop application

Tags: java, c++, qt, google-maps, desktop-application

I am a newbie in this and I have read so many SO questions and other sites, that I am totally confused on how and where to get started. This is how my application works: I have a bunch of Lat/Long values which I want to display using a desktop application via static google maps apis. I already have a working android app that is able to do what I want, but I need a desktop version of it.

From what I have gathered so far, I need to embed a webKit for this. Please guide me as to where to get started (tutorials and sample projects would be great). What are the pros and cons of the different approaches. The sites that I referred to are given below:

QT based:

```
http://www.ics.com/technologies/qt-based-clients-google-apis#.UmgJHxCjcVo
http://code.google.com/p/qt-google-maps/wiki/About
http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2008/07/03/putting-qtwebkit-to-use-with-google-maps/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515598/how-to-add-google-maps-in-my-application-in-qt
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-examples.html
```

Java:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850338/rendering-webpages-with-webkit-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492540/webkit-browser-in-a-java-app
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653949/embeding-gecko-webkit-in-java
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/zzsVgywWsso
```

Comment: You don't need any of that.  See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

Comment: From SLaks link the approach would be like this: Assemble url like documented, use QNetworkAccessManager to download the image, display it in Qt UI (e.g. using QLabel - no Webkit required).

Comment: Thanks. How do I do the same thing in Java?

Comment: Is this a good place to start? https://weblogs.java.net/blog/cajo/archive/2010/10/16/adding-google-maps-your-java-application

Comment: I also found these 2 sites to be very good starting points (for java). http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-maps-without-scripting.html and http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simplewizard/makestaticmap.html

Answer (score 0):

I work with Qt I advise you to work with Qt if you really understood.
Because if you want to use Google Maps with Qt there are two approaches.

- Using QML and Qt C + + and QWebkit
- Using Qt C + +, Javascript and QWebkit

More you already find the best example that you need to start with Qt

Comment: By best example, are you referring to qtjambi examples?