# PYQT4 - Rendering map position from GPS coordinates using Google MAP API QWebView

Tags: google-maps, qt4, qwebview

I'm writing code for a desktop GUI to display a given GPS position on a Map. To do this I'm using :

- python3.2
- Qt4 / PyQt4
- Google Maps API

I've set up a page server that delivers the HTML code from location coordinates.

As we can see [here](http://assistant.open-si.org/webmap/?long=6.659431&lat=46.779231&term=HANDSET#1) it works.

When I try to display the same page in a QWebView widget the result is bad as shown bellow.

[image]

I've checked that Javascript is enabled. On a configuration side everythingthing seems to be OK but in fact Not.

Any  idea about this issue ? already faced ?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all settings enabled:

```
view = new QWebView(this);

QWebSettings *viewSettings;
viewSettings = view->settings();
viewSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::DeveloperExtrasEnabled, true);
viewSettings->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
```

Seems similar to the issue found below:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35387-QWebView-browser-example-alt-parameter-on-web-page

Comment: Also, looking at this issue might be useful to you as develop other apps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515598/how-to-add-google-maps-in-my-application-in-qt