# Google Maps Pac-Man

Tags: python, c++, qt, google-maps

I've got a university project in which I should make the Pac-Man game on Google maps, meaning that the game should find your location on Google maps and use the streets in the map as game map (like the following picture).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MfOx.jpg)

I'm only allowed to use C++ and Python , and I can use Qt for making GUI.
I think I should use Goole Maps API but I don't know how to work with it.
I have no idea how to start this project and I'm wondering if anyone can help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is so abroad for being response here. Please try by yourself and come back with specific questions about your tried.

Answer (score 3):

Break down the problem into smaller chunks until you get them to the point that you can start writing code.

Find a pacman clone out there for Qt or python.

I would also make sure you understand nodes and maze generation.

### JSON Api

The Maps API likely uses a lot of JSON.  Either study: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html

or use `var map_data = JSON.parse(reply);` if you go with QML/javascript

Study up on the google maps api and how to get the data you want.  Then get the data to printout to the console using QDebug statements.

## Graphics

In almost any graphics packages, including Qt, you need to think in terms of the layers and draw elements from the bottom up.  The Qt Widgets framework, the Qt Graphics View framework or the QML framework are all great for drawing these kinds of things...

### QWidget-based or QGraphicsItem-based

Bottom (drawn first)

- Google Maps Image -> stored in a QImage or QPixmap or painter.drawPixmap() or QGraphicsPixmapItem()
- Google Maps Paths/Roads -> QGraphicsPolygonItem or QPainterPath or QLine's or QGraphicsLineItem
- Yellow dots -> painter.drawEllipse() or QGraphicsEllipseItem
- Pacman -> painter.drawArc() or QGraphicsEllipseItem
- Ghosts -> painter.drawPixmap() or QGraphicsSvgItem

Top

Using QGraphicsColorizeEffect you can get the sub elements to colorize nicely or flash.

Movement can be animated with QPropertyAnimations.

If you are considering deploying to mobile/smart phones or tablets, then QML is a preferred option.  Look at the examples in v-play for QML games.  Download the v-play sdk, and then look at all the examples it includes.  The tower defense game is probably similar to what you are making here.

The elements in QML are similar to other Qt classes, but are much more friendly for OpenGL ES 2, and can render and run much faster on mobile platforms.

### QML Elements

Bottom (drawn first)

- Google Maps Image -> Image
- Google Maps Paths/Roads -> Path
- Yellow dots -> Rectangle { height: width; radius: width*.5 } (a rounded rectangle)
- Pacman -> PathArc
- Ghosts -> Image

Top

Colorize or HueSaturation elements to change the color of images.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-animations.html for how to do animations.

### More links

https://qmlbook.github.io/

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html

https://v-play.net/

https://developers.google.com/maps/

https://www.google.com/search?q=maze+in+qt

https://www.google.com/search?q=pacman+in+qt

[How to add Google Maps in my application in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515598/how-to-add-google-maps-in-my-application-in-qt)

Hope that helps.